# CGFloat as Property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How can I store/retrieve a `CGFloat` as a property of a subclassed `UIImageView`? I can set it's value but when I retrieve it, it is corrupt.  `NSString` properties work fine.

.h

```
@property CGFloat myFloat;
```

.m

```
[sender setMyFloat:someFloat];
[sender myFloat];  //<- corrupt?
```

***************  UPDATE *********************

I wanted to thank you for all of your suggestions, they were all correct.  My problem was more complex than I thought.  The sender is a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached to the UIImageview I was having problems with.  The UIPanGestureRecognizer calls the selector move:(id)sender and this is where my problem is.

Within move: I could successfully perform:

```
[[sender view] setMyString:@"test"];
```

and retrieve it back with

```
[[sender view] myString];
```

I could not however set or retrieve any float property at all without including (id)self.  For example:

```
[[sender view] setMyString:@"test"]; //->works

[[sender view] setMyFloat:1.0f]; //->does not work
```

But this works:

```
[[[sender view]self] setMyFloat:1.0f]; //->works
```

This is the strange part which led me to believe I was having a casting problem with my float!  I have a several NSString properties and they return just fine but the CGFloats would not.  Could someone explain to me why somehow I achieve success with strings but the float gets lost here?

Comment: How does corruptness manifest?

Comment: I'm setting a value between -.5 and .5,  It is either returned as 0.0 or -2.000001

Comment: You need to provide context for those two lines of code, or all we can do is take guesses, which isn't particularly constructive. Here's a guess: are you getting the the _same_ `UIImageView` from both those `sender` pointers?

Comment: Do you get any compiler warnings on `[[sender view] setMyFloat:1.0f]`?  What is `sender` declared as?  What is sender's `view` method declared to return?

Comment: that's where posting more code would have helped the community help you. the other suggestion would be that `sender` was not the UIImageView subclass and that's what your problem was. WRT your new question, I still think you'll get better help if you post the code. It is very likely easy to identify the reason for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSWER #2: NSLog syntax?

How are you validating the value after it is set? If you are using NSLog make sure you have the right format code for a float (e.g. `NSLog(@"new float value = %f", myFloat)`.

ORIGINAL ANSWER: wrong setter (was typo in question)

You are calling the wrong setter method. The correct setter is:

```
`[sender setMyFloat:someFloat]`
```

EDIT: OP has updated his question to remove the typo

Comment: Just a typo, sorry.  I still need the answer.

Comment: that would be the answer if the typo was in your actual code. if there is another issue pls post more code. the .h file and the .m file if you have a custom setter would be helpful.

Comment: Your right, you offered the correct answer to the posted question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.h:

@interface SomeClass : UIImageView {
    CGFloat _someFloat;
}

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat someFloat;

@end

.m:

@implementation SomeClass
@synthesize someFloat = _someFloat;
...
...
...
@end
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this will solve the OP's problem?

Comment: The problem is quite vague, he didn't add very much code in general. This exact code works for me (even compiled and tried) so if he were to try and use this code and it were not to work then at least it would give us more information at the least of the source of the issue (I feel that the issue is the logging but he hasn't answered)

Answer (score 1):

You should write `@synthesize myFloat` in your .m to create getter/setter for ivar

Comment: that's good practice but optional. the getter/setter can be manually defined. OP wouldn't be able to compile without a valid getter/setter with the property defined.

Comment: You are right but I assumed that setter/getter are not implemented manually

Comment: right, but the app wouldn't compile (wihout warnings) that way. and if the app was executed w/o the setter being defined the app would crash as the object doesn't implement the setter. Depends what OP means by corrupt. Not a lot of info here.